# Is there a way to convert a Mathematica notebook to Stack Exchange format?

Tags: support

I mean writing questions/answers in *Mathematica* notebook, and converting it to string/file which can be copied and pasted here with good appearance.

I've tried a little. `four spaces` ,`* *`, such *MarkDown* is easy to achieve.
Are you interested in the

## topic:

> Writing in *Mathematica* notebook and Converting that to websites:blogs and here

And is there any functions, templates, or packages, or old posts/questions/discussions/answers about this topic?

Comment: I have developed a custom SE notebook that allows you to write freely in cells, use inline code/text decorations, include images, output,etc. and it will all be automatically converted to valid markdown when you click a button. A few folks have been using it and it works, but is broken right now, because the SE image uploader is broken. I didn't release it publicly because I want to fix a few things add some much needed features first. FWIW, [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HL8Vb.png) is how the notebook looks like for my [Boggle answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5392/5)

Comment: @rm-rf well, I'm so looking forward to trying that, for I;m so poor in editting here,:)

Comment: `CellPrint[ExpressionCell[{},"Text",LineIndent->5]]`
@rm-rf 
hi,here's a little question.
when I use LineIndent to generate the cell,
How to make the indent still maintain it's effect      when copy or save to other places.

Comment: looking forward to see that @rm-rf!

Comment: @rm-rf have you considered sharing the SE notebook in a place like github so that bug fixes and improvements can be outsourced?

Comment: @EdwinMontufar Unfortunately, putting something on GitHub doesn't mean others are really working on it. A good example is the SEUploader which was broken a long time now. This was on GitHub almost from the start but no one volunteered to fix it although it took me only 2 hours. What I want to say is, that this outsourcing doesn't work well and polishing the code to put it on GitHub is additional work one would need time for.

Comment: [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33211495/SENotebook.zip) is a link to the SENotebook package by @rm-rf. Maybe this is not an "official" link, but perhaps it will satisfy some curiosity.

Comment: I am taking advantage of the subject rather than ask a question. There is something to do otherwise? Use a community page and convert to file notebook.