# Has someone created markdown <-> notebook converter?

Tags: discussion

There are some fantastically detailed answers in this forum; I wonder if folks are using Mathematica's notebooks to do the heavy lifting and then exporting as markdown for StackExchange.  Going the other way would be pretty darn convenient as well.

It looks like a [similar question](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/990/13560) has been asked before.

Comment: Welcome! Perhaps this question would be a better fit for meta?

Comment: @YvesKlett Probably, but you need at least a reputation of 5 on this forum to ask there.

Comment: Okay - voted to migrate to meta. See you there ;-)

Comment: Anyway...  related (and on main):http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3535/131 and you can search for `SENotebook` by @rm-rf in chat.

Comment: [This](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/151/13) should be an important part of it. The only thing left is separate markup for code and text cells. Somehow I thought parsing a mixed-content notebook to SE markup was done already - am I wrong?

Comment: @IanTegebo Btw nice games on your website ;-)

Comment: And here's the link to the [SENotebook package](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33211495/SENotebook.zip) Yves mentioned.

Comment: Why is this in meta?

Comment: @wolfies do you think it rather belongs on main? At the time I thought my related question would get more exposure on main,  but I guess both would belong in the same corner (slightly more meta than main IMO).

Comment: @Yves --- yes --- I think it belongs on main ... very much in the mainstream and relevant to all mma users of this site.

Comment: @wolfies vote for migration?